# Remote MariaDB Connection From Windows: Uncaught PDOException: Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 1. Packet size=71

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, raspberry-pi, mariadb

I have a Raspberry Pi that I've upgraded to Buster and am now working on getting everything working again. I have scripts that were set up to run from both a Windows PC and the Raspberry Pi. Prior to upgrading, the Pi was running Wheezy and a MySql server. The scripts were connecting to the MySql server using PDO, and everything was running PHP version 5.(something). Now the Windows PC is running php 7.3.9 and the Pi is running php 7.3.11, and the Pi has MariaDB version 15.1 running. My /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf has the following settings:

```
# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]

#
# * Basic Settings
#
user                    = mysql
pid-file                = /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket                  = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port                    = 3306
basedir                 = /usr
datadir                 = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                  = /tmp
lc-messages-dir         = /usr/share/mysqle

bind-address            = 0.0.0.0

#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size        = 16M
max_allowed_packet     = 16M
thread_stack           = 192K
thread_cache_size      = 8
```

I can connect to the MariaDB successfully using the Raspberry Pi's hostname **from the Raspberry Pi**. 
When I try to connect from the Windows PC I get this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 1. Packet size=71
Next PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
```

The command I've been running for trouble-shooting from the Windows PC is:

```
php -r 'new PDO("mysql:host=PiHostname;port=3306;dbname=Scripting;", "user", "pw");'
```

I've found a few posts regarding this PDO Exception, and it seems like people have the most success either increasing the `max_allowed_packet` size or `wait_timeout` value in the .cnf file and/or setting the PDO ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES attribute to true. I've tried all of these and get the same result every time. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There is no MariaDB version 15.1 . I suggest you create a bug in MariaDB bug tracker,  https://jira.mariadb.org/projects/MDEV , and attach captured tcp dump, that you can collect e.g with wireshark.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading it wrong. When I run `mariadb -V` I get `mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.17-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnueabihf (armv7l) using readline 5.2`

Comment: MariaDB version is 10.3.17 . 15.1 is the version of the command line client, it has no real meaning, and it never changes. I agree version info it shows is confusing.